# Iterate in a directory in python to know how many "PXXX" directory are in this directory

Tags: python, directory, pipeline

For my pipeline in Python I need to iterate through a directory to know how many PXXX directory will be. (Example P001, P002, P003, etc...). The program doesn't know before how many PXXX he will have.

I tried this:

```
for _, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for directory in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(directory))
```

With this output:

```
P001
P002
T1 Gado
TEP
T2 prop
```

Problem is, I want the program to look only into the directory where P001 and P002 are contained and give me back the number of those directories so he can iterate through them after

Thanks

**Solution at my problem:**

I changed my code to :

```
for dirs in os.listdir(path):
    print(dirs)
```

and it worked

Comment: May the folders P001, P002 etc be in subdirectories? Do you know `os.listdir()`?

Comment: Hello, I changed os.walk() to os.listdir() and it worked. Thanks !